# Auto switch keyboard layout to match input language in Ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout, language-support, russian

Is there any software for Ubuntu 16.04 that will automatically switch keyboard layout to match input language if you start to type when wrong layout is on. It must work with any application where you can type a text. Something like Punto Switcher application for Windows (for russian language)?
Or maybe program that be able to make "in-line" conversation of text inputed in wrong layout.

Comment: System-level software?  I hope they never do that!  That'd piss off a large number of users if the system decided to change the keyboard layout to what it *thinks* it should use.  I use QWERTY for all languages I need to use, including English, Français, Deutsch, Italiano, а также русская клавиатура...  **:P**

Comment: I mean "system-wide" software - ONE software that will work FOR almost all application after it starts. To not search solution for every application in which you type text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found soft called "**XNeur**" ([Official site on russian](http://xneur.ru/news/)).
I see some manuals how-to install-it in russian, but other language speakers can use Google Translate or other similar feature / browser plugins.
I install it using [this manual](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/xneur), and even have no problem with not-showing tray icon, as described in many questions/recipies over web.

But this program not worked at all - not switch keyboard layouts.

Luckily i found good discussion (I will add link when my reputation will be bigger) that helps me to find solution.
When the english keyboard language is on, **XNeur** program don't see the other available layouts and so can't start the switcher daemon (service)  cause it think that the only one language is present. On this link also given an example of startup script to correct auto launching of switcher daemon.

To launch XNeur in Ubuntu 16.04 (with Unity interface) i type-and-select "gXNeur" in standard program search window.

To launch (or stop) switcher service manually you can use "Start daemon" menu item from drop-down menu of program's try icon. Just don't forget to switch on non-English language before doing it. In my case daemon stops itself after some settings changes and i need to start it again as described here.

To tune program to your needs you may need to tinker with settings a little bit. But that is worth it.

Program also can correct the text that is already typed in "wrong" language. Hotkey "Shift+Break" is used by default.

Answer (score 1):

There is a relatively convenient option that allows one to choose a keyboard from the main desktop menu:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

It doesn't translate typing, but if you set a keyboard layout to another style, keys will automatically be re-mapped.

The "Keyboard Layout Chart" in the same menu will show how characters are mapped to each key.